# Javascript not working when using wkhtmltopdf testing in terminal

Tags: javascript, html, wkhtmltopdf, macos-mojave

PDF generator wkhtmltopdf (ver. 0.12.5) is not showing any results with javascript.

I am trying to get PDF generator wkhtmltopdf work on my mac. It is rendering the pdf static content, but not simple javascript code (as shown in example below).

with following html in test.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
        <script>
                let d = new Date();
                document.body.innerHTML = "<h1>Today's date is " + d + "</h1>"
        </script>
        <p>testar</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

and testing it in terminal:

`$ wkhtmltopdf --enable-javascript --debug-javascript public/test.html test4.pdf`

output in terminal:

```
Loading pages (1/6)

Warning: file:///Users/anders/vapor/projectDovi/public/test.html:7 SyntaxError: Parse error

Counting pages (2/6)                                               
Resolving links (4/6)                                                       
Loading headers and footers (5/6)                                           
Printing pages (6/6)
Done
```

I expected output showing today's date, but only static text "testar" is showing in my  resulting PDF.

The error I get as shown above is a

> warning: 7 SyntaxError: Parse error

Comment: I know this does not answer your question, but may I suggest looking into using chrome puppeteer to generate your pdf?  You can do more fine control on javascript events and interfactions with the page and will avoid differences in rendering.

Comment: Otherwise, you're going to want to use the `--javascript-delay <msec> ` (default is 200ms) option of wkhtmltopdf in order to let the javascript process. Seems like it wouldn't be necessary in your basic example though.

Comment: I have tried --javascript-delay with 5000 ms. Not working still. I am troubleshooting the wkhtmltopdf for a swift/vapor application, so it will be integrated once I get it to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

wkhtmltopdf `0.12.5` internally uses an old webkit browser and does not support `let`, you must use `var` in your basic example and then it works. Your javascript must be ES5 compatible if you wish to use wkhtmltopdf `0.12.5`.

Please note that  webkit may also render differently than Chromium.